# Do I need to dequeue cells when setting table view's cell style to .subtitle?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I was experimenting with changing the style of the table view cell to be that of `subtitle` in the master view controller (based on given template code), and so I deleted 
`let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)` and instead added:

```
let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

Here is the full `cellForRowAt:` code. It works - but I only have three rows of content, if that makes a difference. Maybe this would stop working if I suddenly had hundreds of entries, though?

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        cell.textLabel!.text = myBookStore.bookList[indexPath.row].title
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = "Default subtitle"
        return cell
    }
```

Should I be calling this dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:for:) method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do that.

Use always the `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:for:)` method and change the style of the cell in the storyboard (Interface Builder).

If you need cells with both `basic` and `subtitle` style create a second cell in Interface Builder

Comment: Thanks @vadian. Is it possible to change the style of the cell in the code as well as calling dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:for:)?

Comment: No, it's not because the style is not settable in code after dequeueing the cell.